# Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_list()

Tags: php, macos, printing, xampp

So Im busy with this project that involves printing. I found a class online to do so. But when I try to test it, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_list() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/barcode/Sample.php on line 9
```

And I know that I probably should install an extention, but how which one and how to do so? I use Xampp on OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Post the "class you found online" if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printer extension working only on Windows

Answer (score 0):

`printer_list()` id deprecate in new php